# Akamai Token Protection stream cant play in IOS

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, urlencode, http-live-streaming, akamai

I am a developer in an IpTV. We have developed our application in Android and now we want to move on IOS devices. Akamai is our CDN.
At the moment we have a simple IOS application which is able to play HLS streams. We can navigate through each channel and all streams are played correctly.
To protect our streams we planned to use token. We already have implemented the token on android but I am now experiencing some difficulties on IOS. Streams protected with token won't play, the screen remains black.

Here is an example of my stream

[http://this_is_my_stream_protected_with_token.m3u8?**token**=exp=1432902926~acl=](http://this_is_my_stream_protected_with_token.m3u8?__token__=exp=1432902926~acl=)*~hmac=1e1d2afa7e7fbca72b0da6f5820ba1063446631e75fea80093c8183b619c0acc

If i try to play this stream in my application,screen remains black in the other hand if i open with VLC or a player in webbrowser (http://www.flashls.org/latest/examples/chromeless/) it playes correctly.

I have created a function that makes a http request on that link and server response is:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=1629884,CODECS="avc1.77.31,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=640x360
 chunklist.m3u8?__token__=exp%3D1432902926%7Eacl%3D*%7Ehmac%3D1e1d2afa7e7fbca72b0da6f5820ba1063446631e75fea80093c8183b619c0acc
```

To make sure my application generate correctly the token, i made it hardcoded and i still have the same problem.

Since this is not an Akamai problem neither token generation problem, it makes me believe that perhaps i need to encode the stream somehow in the player. I have read everywhere about this problem and still don't have a working solution

Here is my player code:

```
    var param = ["auth":encryption.Token()] as Dictionary<String,String>;
            WebHelper().httpPostNSString(currentChannel.channelTokenUrl, params: param, consumeData: { (nsstring) -> () in

               //this is a custom method. it makes a post HttpRequest. It takes Token Url path and Dictionary with parameters and it returns the respnse data converted to String.

                token = nsstring;
                _URL_ += token;
                _URL_ = _URL_.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet());

               //remove spaces just in case (this is a 'MUST' in Android)

                var address = "http://this_is_my_stream_protected_with_token.m3u8?__token__=exp=1432902926~acl=*~hmac=1e1d2afa7e7fbca72b0da6f5820ba1063446631e75fea80093c8183b619c0acc"

                let url = NSURL(string: address)

                self.moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: url)
                self.moviePlayer?.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.None;

                if(self.db.select.getStringValue(forKey: self.db.STRING_VALUE_CURRENT_CHANNEL) == nil){
                    self.db.insert.CoreData_Insert(value: "-1", coreDataKey: self.db.STRING_VALUE_CURRENT_CHANNEL)
                }

                Logs().sendHit(currentChannel.channelNumber, accessway: self.access_way, lastchannel: self.db.select.getStringValue(forKey: self.db.STRING_VALUE_CURRENT_CHANNEL).value, username: self.db.select.getStringValue(forKey: self.db.STRING_VALUE_USERNAME).value);

                self.db.delete.deleteEntityFromCore(entityName: "StringValue", field_Name: "key", field_Value: self.db.STRING_VALUE_CURRENT_CHANNEL);

                self.db.insert.CoreData_Insert(value: currentChannel.channelNumber, coreDataKey: self.db.STRING_VALUE_CURRENT_CHANNEL);

//we save some data and than proceed to play selected channel.

                if let player = self.moviePlayer{

                    //save the new channel

                    player.view.frame = self.view.bounds
                    player.prepareToPlay()
                    player.scalingMode = .AspectFill
                    self.view.addSubview(player.view)
                    self.view.bringSubviewToFront(self.two_way_channel); 
                    player.play();

                    //send hits
                }
            })
```

Thank You

Comment: wondering if you've managed to solve it?

Comment: How you are appending token to chunk_list and .ts ?